# zend2: Oracle11g: Exception while retrieving columnNames from Metadata class

Tags: php, oracle11g, zend-framework2

iam using zendFramework2.5.1 with Oracle 11g. Database connectivity/DML queries executing fine.
i need to export the column names of a table present in oracleDB. i use **Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway** for DB connectivity. i learnt that by using **Zend\Db\Metadata\Metadata** column names could be retrived. Using the $tableObject (as shown below), i retrieved the existing adapter object and table name. No issues here.

```
$metadataObject = new Metadata($tableObject->getAdapter());
$tableName = $tableObject->getTable();
```

But when below code executes, exception occurs.

```
$metadataTable = $metadataObject->getTable($tableName);
```

**Exception**

```
Zend\Db\Adapter\Exception\RuntimeException

File:
C:\wamp\www\zfc2\vendor\zendframework\zend-db\src\Adapter\Driver\Oci8\Statement.php:260
Message:
ORA-01745: invalid host/bind variable name
Stack trace:
#0 C:\wamp\www\zfc2\vendor\zendframework\zend-db\src\Metadata\Source\OracleMetadata.php(137):    Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Oci8\Statement->execute(Array)
#1 C:\wamp\www\zfc2\vendor\zendframework\zend-db\src\Metadata\Source\AbstractSource.php(316): Zend\Db\Metadata\Source\OracleMetadata->loadConstraintData('CSS_MILIBRIS_US...', 'LNK1DB')
#2 C:\wamp\www\zfc2\vendor\zendframework\zend-db\src\Metadata\Source\AbstractSource.php(142): Zend\Db\Metadata\Source\AbstractSource->getConstraints('CSS_MILIBRIS_US...', 'LNK1DB')
#3 C:\wamp\www\zfc2\vendor\zendframework\zend-db\src\Metadata\Metadata.php(178): Zend\Db\Metadata\Source\AbstractSource->getTable('CSS_MILIBRIS_US...', NULL)
#4 C:\wamp\www\zfc2\module\Kiosque\src\Kiosque\Controller\LandingController.php(76): Zend\Db\Metadata\Metadata->getTable('CSS_MILIBRIS_US...')
#5 C:\wamp\www\zfc2\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Controller\AbstractActionController.php(82):
```

i referred the  [ZendDBManual Link](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.db.metadata.html). and tried the same. i analyzed the exception,but couldn't proceed further with what i have analyzed.
 What i observed going through websites is, this has something to do with accessing restricted variables present in oracle (am not sure about it).
. Any help in providing solution for this issue is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

i got a solution for this. i analyzed/browsed/went through the logs. i found out that zend provides a metadata class for oracle which is

```
use Zend\Db\Metadata\Source\OracleMetadata;
```

i kindof misthought the function which could retrieve column names of a table. The correct function to retrieve the column names of table is **getColumnNames**

```
$metadata = new OracleMetadata($tableObject->getAdapter());
$myTableName = $tableObject->getTable();
$metadataTable = $metadata->getColumnNames($myTableName);
```

This same logic has to work with Metadata class too i think. But i didnt verify it

```
use Zend\Db\Metadata\Metadata
```